# How to get value from Overflow Flutter

Tags: flutter

I want to know how to get value (height, width) that show when overflow, or if someone have the better way to resize modal height when it overflow?

more info >
I just build custom Textfield and create my own validator when text error is show my modal gonna overflow.

below is what I tried.

```
double modalheight (BuildContext context) {
    double baseheight = 546;
    if (MediaQuery.of(context).size.width < 430) {
        baseheight += 16;
    } else {
        if (isdata_error = false) {
            baseheight + 30;
        }
    }
    return baseheight;
}
```